# Wikipedia API JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, api, wikipedia

I want to make a Python list of all of Vincent van Gogh's paintings out of the JSON file from a Wikipedia API call. Here is my URL that I use to make the request:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=list%20of%20works%20by%20Vincent%20van%20Gogh&Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

As you can see if you open the URL in your browser, it's a huge blob of text. How can I begin to extract the titles of paintings from this massive JSON return? I have done a great deal of research before asking this question, and tried numerous methods to solve it. It would be helpful if this JSON file was a useful dictionary to work with, but I can't make sense of it. How would you extract names of paintings from this JSON file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of directly parsing the results of JSON API calls, use a [python wrapper](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia):

```
import wikipedia

page = wikipedia.page("List_of_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh")
print page.links
```

There are also [other clients and wrappers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code#Python).

Alternatively, here's an option using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
>>> table = soup.find('table', class_="wikitable")
>>> for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
...     print(row.find_all('td')[1].text)
... 
Still Life with Cabbage and Clogs
Crouching Boy with Sickle, Black chalk and watercolor
Woman Sewing, Watercolor
Woman with White Shawl
...
```

Comment: I just tried that, got an error, No Module named "wikipedia." I'm using Python 3.4 by the way.

Comment: @rami7 you need to install the module first.

Comment: As a second question, since returning all the links on the page returns more than just titles of paintings, is there a way to filter out worthless links? For instance links to the museum which holds the painting.

Comment: @rami7 not sure how to filter irrelevant links, but I've added an alternative solution, check the update.

Comment: Yes! That solution is even better, especially because I was trying to use BeautifulSoup earlier and failing at it. I knew I had a table, and various <td> divs containing my info, but could not make it work. I see you used indexing to pull the relevant data from the table. You da man alec.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to have your list in a panda dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Vincent_van_Gogh'
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "wikitable"})[0] # 0 is for the 1st table in this particular page
df.head()
```